# Hosting an ASP Web Api inside a WPF app wont stop gracefully

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an Asp Core 3.1 app hosting a rest API. It can run standalone, but I have a WPF app that I want to be able to also host the rest API while it is running.

I have gotten this working, but my problem is that when I close my last WPF window, I tell ASP's IHost to shutdown and it leaves the process open. I have recreated the problem with brand new projects with just a couple modifications:

In the WPF project, I have removed the StartupURI and use the Startup and Exit events:

```
 private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
 {
     RestApiProgram.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
     MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
     window.Show();
 }

 private void Application_Exit(object sender, ExitEventArgs e)
 {
     RestApiProgram.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
 }
```

In the Asp project, I have modified the Program class so I can call start and stop on the IHost:

```
 private static IHost _host;
 //Main is called when running the ASP project by itself
 public static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
 }

 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
     Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
         .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
         {
             webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
         });

 //StartAsync is called by the WPF app
 public static Task StartAsync(CancellationToken token)
 {
     _host = CreateHostBuilder(Array.Empty<string>()).Build();
     return _host.StartAsync(token);
 }

 public static async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken token)
 {
     using (_host)
     {
         await _host.StopAsync(token);
     }
 }
```

When I close the main window, my WPF app calls StopAsync, I see the message "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application is shutting down..." in the output, but the process does not shut down. When I pause, it is stuck waiting for the StopAsync to complete. Any ideas why?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But I did not manage to solve it. Are there any further ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should await the `Task` returned by `StopAsync`.

To prevent the WPF app from shutting down before the task has completed, you could handle the `OnClosing` event of the window:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Closing += WhenClosing;
    }
    ...

    private async void WhenClosing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        await RestApiProgram.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        this.Closing -= WhenClosing;
        Close();
    }
}
```

The same goes for `StartAsync`:

```
private async void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    await RestApiProgram.StartAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
    window.Show();
 }
```

Calling `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` is almost always a bad idea as it might cause a deadlock.

Comment: So putting the StopAsync in the window close and switching to `await` almost did the trick. The last piece of it is that I had to call `_host.StopAsync()` without waiting, dispose of the _host, then return the task so it can be awaited. Can't say I understand fully why it has to be done this way, but it even allowed all of my `BackgroundService`'s to exit gracefully.